# why dynamoDB will execute scan function twice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm a starter on aws. I'm currently trying to get all results from a table. But I realize that the function `dynamodb.scan` (or the callback function) will execute twice.
My code:

```js
var params = {
    TableName: DataTableName
};
const selection = () =>{
    dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data){
        if(err) console.log(err, err.stack);
        else console.log(data);
        console.log("abcdefg")
    });
    return(
    <Flex direction="column">
    <SelectField
      label="Animals"
      options={myData}
    ></SelectField>
    </Flex>    
    )
};
```

In my console, the data and `abcdefg` will be printed out twice.

Comment: Perhaps because `selection()` is being called twice?

Comment: I don't think so it was called twice....

Comment: Given that both the data from dynamo and abcdefg is being printed twice, it seems that it has nothing to do with dynamo, but rather that selection() is called twice.

Comment: But if I only keep `console.log("abcdefg")`, this line will only be printed out once. @Trygvi Laksafoss

Comment: Isolate this code from your React code. If you move the scan code out to your mainline JavaScript you'll be able to confirm that it only makes the callback once. Then you can debug what's going on with `selection()`.